# mysql -- using "read local" lock and "low priority" insert

Tags: mysql, locking

I have a table where I want SELECT to have priority over INSERT, so i do LOW PRIORITY inserts;

I've read that locking the table with a READ LOCAL lock while reading from the table allows inserts to be made concurrently with reading in non-fragmented MyIsam tables (because it ads rows at the end of the table).

If i do the SELECTs with READ LOCAL lock and the INSERTs with LOW PRIORITY, does using LOW PRIORITY makes the INSERTs wait even if the READ LOCAL allows acces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

"Note that LOW_PRIORITY should normally not be used with MyISAM tables because doing so disables concurrent inserts"

In most cases INSERTs won't block a SELECT in any noticeable way as inserts are usually very fast (especially with MyISAM) but complex SELECT queries can be quite slow.